# ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, netbeans-12

I'm doing a maven project with WildFly as a server, although the web page opens, it shows that the localhost isn't sending any data

that's what shows on my WildFly output regarding to errors:

```
14:37:21,257 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /Professores/}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [225] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:149)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:170)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:255)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:187)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:117)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:163)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:606)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2160)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:610)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:491)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:586)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:328)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

14:37:21,269 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /Professores/}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [225] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:149)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:170)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:255)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:187)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:117)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:163)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:606)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2160)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:610)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:491)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:586)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:328)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

14:37:21,582 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /Professores/}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [225] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:149)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:170)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:255)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:187)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:117)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:163)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:606)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2160)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:610)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:491)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:586)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:328)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

14:37:22,618 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /Professores/}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [225] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:149)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:170)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:255)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:187)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:117)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:163)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:606)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2160)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:610)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:491)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:586)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:328)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

14:37:22,921 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /Professores/}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [225] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:149)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:170)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:255)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:187)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:117)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:163)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:606)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2160)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:610)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:491)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:586)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:328)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

14:37:28,252 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /Professores/}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [225] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:149)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:170)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:255)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:187)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:117)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:163)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:606)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2160)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:610)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:491)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:586)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:328)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Given the error message it looks like you're writing an invalid character to the cookie. What are you writing to the cookie?

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this, its part of an university project. Never used WildFly before, i mostly used tomcat.
anyways, what do you mean by that? where can i check this? I'm using netbeans 12 together with a databank on mysql using the WildFly server, that I only connected, and added a dependency on the pom to "work", for now only opens my browser but saying there's no data received.

Comment: In your application are you writing any cookie data?

Comment: I don't think so, all I did was some java codes, (Bean, RN, DAO, Entity), some xhtml and adding dependencies on the pom.xml

Comment: Given the error message it could be a request attribute or a cookie. The simple test is to ensure you're only using Latin characters. It could be a simple issues of requiring some encoding of values, but there's not much to go on with just a stack trace and no code or values.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways, so i should check just those codes, right? there's nothing wrong with the connection between netbeans and wildfly server, correct?

Comment: I would assume not. It just looks like invalid or non-encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps and it will work fine.

1. Download this `jdk1.8.0_65` version java.
2. Update the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` in Environment Variables.
3. Deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I installed Eclipse Temurin 11.0.15 on my new computer. Installing an older JDK (from Oracle) really helps.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32141191)